# Chrome / Safari firing click event at different times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue recipe portal with a filter on the side where users can select a given tag.

```
<filter-button 
    v-on:click="filterByTag()" 
    label="selectedTags.indexOf(<%= tag %>) != -1"
    :isChecked="selectedTags.indexOf(<%= tag %>) != -1"
></filter-button>
```

After selecting the tag, my vue code checks whether it was a check vs. uncheck event, and then makes a call to my backend:

```
filterByTag: function() {
  let check_status = !this.isChecked
  console.log(check_status)
  check_status ? this.$emit('tag_selected', this.tag) :
                 this.$emit('tag_deselected', this.tag)
}
```

This `console.log(check_status)` call shows `true` on Chome, and `false` on Safari, resulting in correct filtering for Chrome and incorrect fitlering on Safari.

**Is there a better way to do this check to ensure the same response across all browsers?**

Here is my `filter-button` component:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="filter-button">
    <div class="form-check my-3">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" 
            type="checkbox" 
            v-model="isChecked" 
            v-on:click="filterByTag()"
        >
        {{ tag.name }}
        <span class="form-check-sign">
            <span class="check"></span>
        </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried e.preventDefault(); in the filterByTag() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using v-on:mouseup. This will ensure that the change has fired. You could also use a v-on:change.

```
<filter-button 
    v-on:change="filterByTag()" 
    label="selectedTags.indexOf(<%= tag %>) != -1"
    :isChecked="selectedTags.indexOf(<%= tag %>) != -1"
></filter-button>
```